# Proxy implementation with caching system

Tags: c, caching, network-protocols

I'm trying to implement a simple proxy server and so far so good, I've managed to do the GET method correctly but now I have to implement a caching for it. The idea behind it being that when I get the following commands:

- GET www.google.com
- GET www.cplusplus.com
- GET www.google.com

The second time I'm asked to get the informatiom from google it should be from my caching system. I've been thinking and the best way to do this is to implement a simple filing system where I store the information received in files and then read it whenever I find the file to exist. The only trouble I'm having is that I can't create files such as http://elf.cs.edu.ro/

Here is my code so you understand what I'm doing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>

void error(char* msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {

int count = 0;
FILE *in;
FILE *out;
pid_t pid;
struct sockaddr_in addr_in,cli_addr,serv_addr;
struct hostent* host;
int sockfd,newsockfd;

if(argc<2)
    error("./proxy <port_no>");

printf("\n*****WELCOME TO PROXY SERVER*****\n");

bzero((char*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
bzero((char*)&cli_addr, sizeof(cli_addr));

serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[1]));
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;


sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
if(sockfd<0)
    error("Problem in initializing socket");

if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
    error("Error on binding");


listen(sockfd,50);
int clilen=sizeof(cli_addr);



startpoint:

newsockfd=accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr,&clilen);

if(newsockfd<0)
error("Problem in accepting connection");

pid=fork();
//printf("Pid is: %d\n", pid);
if(pid==0) {
    sites saves[10];
    int noOfSites = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in host_addr;
    int flag=0,newsockfd1,n,port=0,i,sockfd1;
    char buffer[510],t1[300],t2[300],t3[10], aux[510];
    char* temp=NULL;
    bzero((char*)buffer,500);
    recv(newsockfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
    //printf("%s\n",buffer);
    sscanf(buffer,"%s %s %s",t1,t2,t3);
    //printf("%s\n",buffer);

    if (((strncmp(t1,"GET",3)==0))&&((strncmp(t3,"HTTP/1.0",8)==0)||(strncmp(t3,"HTTP/1.0",8)==0))&&(strncmp(t2,"http://",7)==0)) {
        strcpy(t1,t2);
        int saved = 0;
        flag=0;

        for(i=7;i<strlen(t2);i++) {
            if(t2[i]==':') {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
         // printf("The site to GET is : %s\n",t2);
        temp=strtok(t2,"//");
        if (flag==0) {
            port=80;
            temp=strtok(NULL,"/");
        }
        else {
            temp=strtok(NULL,":");
        }

        sprintf(t2,"%s",temp);
        host=gethostbyname(t2);

                    int it;
          for (it = 0; it < noOfSites; it++){
            printf("Site saved is: %s\n", saves[it].site);
            if (strcmp(saves[it].site,t2) == 0){
                saved = 1;
                out = fopen(t2, "r");
                printf("We have cache!\n");
            }
        }
        if(flag==1) {
            temp=strtok(NULL,"/");
            port=atoi(temp);
        }


        strcat(t1,"^]");
        temp=strtok(t1,"//");
        temp=strtok(NULL,"/");
        if(temp!=NULL)
            temp=strtok(NULL,"^]");


        bzero((char*)&host_addr,sizeof(host_addr));
        host_addr.sin_port=htons(port);
        host_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
        bcopy((char*)host->h_addr,(char*)&host_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,host->h_length);

        sockfd1=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
        newsockfd1=connect(sockfd1,(struct sockaddr*)&host_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr));
        sprintf(buffer,"\nConnected to %s  IP - %s\n",t2,inet_ntoa(host_addr.sin_addr));
        if(newsockfd1<0)
            error("Error in connecting to remote server");

        bzero((char*)buffer,sizeof(buffer));
        if(temp!=NULL)
            sprintf(buffer,"GET /%s %s\r\nHost: %s\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n",temp,t3,t2);
        else
            sprintf(buffer,"GET / %s\r\nHost: %s\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n",t3,t2);




        if (saved == 1){
            printf("Are we ever here\n");
            n = send(sockfd1,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
            char * line = NULL;
            size_t len = 0;
            ssize_t read;
            int count = 0;
            if (n<0)
                error("Error writing to socket");
            else {
                while ((read = getline(&line, &len, out)) != -1) {
                    //printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
                    if (count > 0)
                        write(newsockfd,line,read);
                    if (strcmp(line,"\r\n") == 0)
                        count++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (saved == 0){
            //printf("We are only here\n");
            strcpy(saves[noOfSites].site,t2);
            noOfSites++;
            printf("The new site file is: %d\n", noOfSites);


            in = fopen(t2,"w");
            n=send(sockfd1,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
            printf("I have opened for writing: %s\n\n\n\n\n\n",t2);

            if(n<0)
                error("Error writing to socket");
            else {
                do {
                    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
                    n=recv(sockfd1,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
                    fwrite(buffer, n, 1, stdout);
                    printf("\n");
                    fwrite(buffer, n, 1, in);
                    if(!(n<=0))
                        write(newsockfd,buffer,n);
                } while(n>0);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        send(newsockfd,"400 : BAD REQUEST\nONLY HTTP REQUESTS ALLOWED",18,0);
    }
    close(sockfd1);
    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
else {
    close(newsockfd);
    goto startpoint;
}
return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I don't want someone to do it for me, just some ideas as to how you would do it so I might have a chance. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a general key/value data store. You could either use a hash table in memory, use a simple database like gdbm, or pick a more advanced database like MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I am genuinely sorry if I made some mistakes along the way and I'm not posting good questions, but I have managed to figure this one out on my own. The trouble i was having was that when I was trying to create files where to store my information from the get commands, i was trying to create files with names like: http://something.com/ it would not let me as the / is prohibited when trying to create files from C programs (or so I've understood). My task was simple, to replace the / with something else (in my case _ ) and it all worked out just well. Thank you for trying and I am really sorry if I've made you guys lose time while trying to understand what I was saying.

So to be more precise, what I am trying to do is when I'm receiveing a get command the second time (same get command with same link) I would need to get the information from the file I created the first time I received the command. It should be like this:

- GET www.something.com HTTP/1.0 -> i need to create a file with the name "www.something.com", store all the information from the site in that file and then close it, and of course send that information to the socket opened for communication
- GET www.something.com HTTP/1.0 -> i need to open the file that was created by the previous command and get the information to send from that file

AGAIN, sorry if I've troubled someone. Thank you very much!